# Rsync include-from, exclude-from without source directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rsync

I am working on a backup script but got some problems with my script, can you help me?

```sh
INCLUDE="/data/scripts/include.txt"
EXCLUDE="/data/scripts/exclude.txt"
DST="/backupdir"

    rsync \
      --archive \
      --recursive \
      --include-from $INCLUDE \
      --exclude-from $EXCLUDE \
      --hard-links \
      --perms \
      --executability \
      --owner \
      --group \
      --human-readable \
      --verbose \
      --progress \
      --delete-before \
      --stats \
      --timeout=300 \
      -e "ssh -i $SSHKEY" $USER@$IP:$DST
```

```sh
#include
/root
/data
/etc/httpd
/data/lost+found
```

```sh
#exclude
/data/www/html/nextcloud/public_html/data/index.html
/data/www/html/nextcloud/public_html/data/nextcloud.log
/data/www/html/nextcloud/public_html/data/updater.log
/data/www/html/nextcloud/public_html/data/updater-*
```

My question is, how do I tell rsync to rsync everything thats in the include-file , exclude everything thats in the exclude-file without giving him a source path?

Answer (score 1):

The manual says you have to have a source directory.

You should use the list in your include file as a list of source directories to loop through and rsync from:

```
for dir in /root /data /etc/httpd
do
    rsync OPTIONS $dir DEST
done
```

*Or*, you can make `/` your source directory, and have something like `/*` in your exclude pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One might think that the files listed in --include-from are specifically searched for like the source argument(s), but such isnot how rsync works.

Instead, rsync searches from the source directory specified and downward only if --recursive is specified. As files are found, rsync compares them to --include-from. If a match is found, then the file is specifically included and searching for includes/excludes stops.

A problem arises because the entire source tree has been included by the --recursive option. Therefore, --exclude='*' must exist AFTER the --include-from option to remove files which are not matched in the --include-from files. This way, the entire source tree will be scanned, but only the --include-from files will be included.

Another problem arises because the source tree is searched in a top-down fashion. All required parent directories must also be specified in the --include-from list or they will be removed by the --exclude='*' and their children will not be considered.

Most man pages are beyond minimal while info pages are the other extreme, but reading the rsync man pages was the best thing I every did. Rsync is very well organized.